# How do I manipulate a string within a csv to remove sections from all strings in a select column?

Tags: perl, csv

I have been working on a script that pulls down data from a file and converts it to a more usuable format. So far I have managed to get the data to csv in the format shown below.

```
data1   data2   name        data3
00958c  JMOP    Nixon, Richard  e004a
00967c  CMLL    Dole, Bob             a006n
```

What I am trying to firgure out is how to take the data in the "name" column and make a new variable like:

```
Rnixon01
Bdole01
```

I am guessing I would use the `s///` operator somehow, but I am still very new to perl. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: That's not CSV - it's tab-separated

Comment: @Borodin, a meaningless distinction.

Comment: @ikegami: Not at all. The separator character never appears in the data in tab-separated files, which avoids the need to quote data fields and escape the quote character.

Comment: @Borodin, That's not true, you still have to quote data fields or escape the quote character if the quote character is present in a field. Well, if we were generating the file.

Comment: @ikegami: Why would you quote the data if it can't contain the separator character? I don't think I have *ever* seen quoted data in a tab-separated file.

Comment: @Borodin, I said one would quote the data when it does contain the separator character, so how can I possibly answer your question? It's not surprising you've never seen one; how often do you put tabs in your data?

Comment: @Borodin, The distinction of separator is meaningless; it's just an argument passed to the parser's constructor.

Comment: @ikegami: What you said was "...if the *quote* character is present in a field". If you meant the separator character then, as I said, the [separator character never appears in the data](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values). That is *different* from CSV data.

Comment: @Borodin, Again, it can! (You think that's the only tab separated format???)

Comment: @ikegami: Your comments are tedious and contrary. Yes, it is the only tab-separated standard that I know about, and it is a significant one as the IANA governs the low-level standards of the internet, and their standard also corresponds to common usage. If you are talking about any conceivable data format that has tabs as separators then of course you are right. But in that context no one can say anything useful as there may or may not be other significant characters in the syntax and the data cannot be processed at all.

Comment: @Borodin, You keep saying something that exists doesn't exist, even when someone tells you repeatedly it does exist. You're the one being contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that uses the `s` operator directly:

```
$name =~ s{ 
    ([^, ]+)    # Everything up to the space or comma, the last name
    \s* , \s*   # Comma, potentially with space around it
    (\w)        # The first letter of the first name
    .*          # The rest (which we don't want to capture, but want to replace)
 }{
     uc($2) .   # First letter (upper case)
     lc($1)     # last name (lower case)
 }xmse;
```

How to increment the counter: see other answers.

Yes, this is a very elaborate version of regular expressions, but may be something you will encounter "in the wild", and should probably also be writing. The `x` in `xms` lets you add whitespace and even comments to your regular expressions, the `e` tells Perl to evaluate the second block as code. And yes, the `s{}{}` works, even with nested braces ;-)

For more on the syntax possibilities of the regex operators, see [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: Thank you so much, that gives me exactly what I was looking for. Also, thank you for the perldoc link as I didn't know there was so much documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already know how to [parse the CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS), and that you're simply looking for

```
my ($lname, $fname) = split /,\s*/, $name;
my $id = uc(substr($fname, 0, 1)) . lc($lname);
$id .= sprintf '%02d', ++$counts{$id};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
$name =~ s/([^,]+),\s*([^,]).*/$2$1/
```

and then adding the digits at the end. I assume those digits are a sequence number to differentiate, say, multiple `RNixon`s. In that case you need a hash to keep count of the number of times each name has occurred.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my %sequence;
for ('Nixon, Richard', 'Dole, Bob') {
  my $name = s/([^,]+),\s*([^,]).*/$2$1/r;
  $name = sprintf '%s%02d', $name, ++$sequence{$name};
  print "$name\n";
}
```

**output**

```
RNixon01
BDole01
```